# Running gunicorn-nginx gets a 500 server error when visiting URL

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have run my bin bash gunicorn file and yes, it boots me my 13 workers without errors but:

aside from that, if I correctly understand how things work, this code (ip changed) should allow me to see my web, because gunicorn is replacing runserver

```
[2023-12-20 21:50:45 +0100] [35586] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-12-20 21:50:45 +0100] [35586] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2023-12-20 21:50:45 +0100] [35586] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/home/boards/run/gunicorn.sock (35586)
[2023-12-20 21:50:45 +0100] [35586] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-12-20 21:50:45 +0100] [35591] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 35591
```

but I get a server error 500
Question: Should I be able to see my web through that command? If yes, why am I not seeing it?

Then ginx simply calls that gunicorn file, so, if I haven't been able to see my web, nginx won't help at all. That means that the gunicorn despite booting workers is not doing any good?
Supervisor won't help either, it is just to restart gunicorn whenever is down.

for the curious, my gunicorn file is this (web address changed)

```
NAME="boards"                                     # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=/home/boards/me                      # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/home/boards/run/gunicorn.sock  # we will communicte using this unix socket
USER=boards                                       # the user to run as
GROUP=boards                                      # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=13                                    # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=estate.settings            # which settings file should Django use
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=estate.wsgi
                                                 # WSGI module name
PATH_HOME="/home/boards"
PATH_ENV="$PATH_HOME/venv"
echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source $PATH_ENV/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)
exec gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
```

The error reads:

```
request: "GET /.env HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/boards/run/gunicorn.sock:/.env", host: "222.222.22.22"
2023/12/20 21:38:29 [crit] 35388#35388: *12 connect() to unix:/home/boards/run/gunicorn.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 111.111.111.111, server: myweb.com, request: "POST / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/boards
```

/run/gunicorn.sock:/", host: "222.222.22.22"

My nginx is:

```
upstream app_server {
  # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
  # to return a good HTTP response (in case the Unicorn master nukes a
  # single worker for timing out).

  server unix:/home/boards/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}


server {
    listen 80;
   # listen[::]:80;
    server_name myweb.com 111.111.111.111 www.myweb.com;  # here can also be the IP address of the server

    keepalive_timeout 5;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /home/boards/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /home/boards/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/boards/staticfiles/;
    }

    # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }

}
```

UPDATE
I have reached the view  part of my code. Because when I ran the gunicorn like this ./gunicorn_start all my 13 workers booted but on top of that I was getting this:

```
[2023-12-20 20:54:24 +0000] [35603] [DEBUG] GET /favicon.ico
[2023-12-20 20:54:24 +0000] [35601] [DEBUG] GET /
[2023-12-20 20:54:25 +0000] [35603] [DEBUG] Ignoring EPIPE
2023-12-20 20:54:25.372261+00:00
Hostname: vmi1520937
IP Address: 127.0.1.1
La ip 127011
[2023-12-20 20:54:31 +0000] [35596] [DEBUG] GET /
2023-12-20 20:54:32.245455+00:00
Hostname: vmi1520937
IP Address: 127.0.1.1
La ip 127011
```

and that is part of the code that refers to the index.html page, however, I can't get to see that page.

Comment: So `400 bad request` signifies a client error, not the server. Can you check gunicorn logs using `sudo journalctl -u gunicorn` and paste so I can advise better.

Comment: Hello. Deep thanks for taking a look at it. I have done some changes and I am back at bad gateway 502 nginx. I past the error log and will include nginx

Comment: does everything work as expected if you run the app through gunicorn directly? And does the gunicorn.sock file exist when you run the gunicorn command?

Comment: Hello, when I run the gunicorn directly I still don't get the to see my web but I got to see in the console that it had output some print statements that were in my index.html page. With regards to the gunicorn.sock yes, it is created while it is running. I went to the run directory and it is there while it runs.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the `python3 manage.py runserver myweb.com:8000` wit `debug = True` in order to see debugging code as the nginx logs did not give any error, and the gunicorn ran fine. The thing was that:
While I had created the database I had not imported the tables yet, hence the server error. Those tables were of the kind of managed=False in the models as they existed separately from the Model creation.
It had to be something in the code of the project since nginx did create the sock in the run directory and gunicorn did boot the 13 workers.
First time ever I upload a django project to a bare metal vps. Not a trivial struggle to understand the configuration of all the nginx, gunicorn, supervisor files and how they communicate with each other if you are on your own. Huge gratitude to all those who tried and I am sorry I made it difficult for you.